# mongodb primary showing too many open connection end connection log messages

Tags: mongodb

we are facing slow mongo updates. Looking at the primary's log files, i see connection opening and closing every second or so. These connections are from arbiter and the secondary. I am wondering if those connections are heartbeat connections. So does secondary and arbiter open and close connections with primary every second or two seconds or do they send heart beats over a dedicated open connection?

The same issue is with secondary mongo server

Comment: As I remember the heartbeat should be happening every 10s. There's a possibility that you have many members which would lead to more frequent heartbeat. You can group them by source IP to find out if it's every 10s. This should be a normal behavior. While the slow udpates maybe related to system bottleneck. Have you tried [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) and [montostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) to analyse it?

Answer (score 0):

config mongod with quiet log (YAML)

```
systemLog:
   quiet: true
```

or

```
quiet=true
```

or

```
--quiet
```

if you use one-line config